# Displaying mysql query results with node.js ejs express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am having issues with querying my mysql database and displaying the results as a table using express and ejs.

This is what I have for my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10, 
    host        : 'host',
    user        : 'user',
    password    : 'password',
    database    : 'database'
});

module.exports.pool = pool;

...
var list = {};
app.get("/pokemon", function(req,res){
pool.query('SELECT p.pokemon_id AS `pokemon_id`, p.name AS `pokemon_name`, 
t1.name AS `type1`, t2.name AS `type2`, p.evolution_level AS `evLevel` FROM `pokemon` p INNER JOIN `type` t1 ON t1.type_id=p.type1 INNER JOIN `type` t2 ON 
t2.type_id=p.type2', function(err,result){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        } else {
            list = {listResults: result};
            res.render('listResults', list);                
        }
    })
});
...
```

And for the ejs file

```html
<table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">#</th>
                      <th scope="col">Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Type 1</th>
                      <th scope="col">Type 2</th>
                      <th scope="col">Evolution Level</th>
                      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                      <th scope="col">Update</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <% listResults.forEach(function (pokemon) { %>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row"><%= pokemon.pokemon_id %></th>
                      <td><%= pokemon.pokemon_name %></td>
                      <td><%= pokemon.type1 %></td>
                      <td><%= pokemon.type2 %></td>
                      <td><%= pokemon.evLevel %></td>
                      <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                      <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="#" role="button">Update</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  <% }) %>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

When I try going to the page I get an error saying 'listResults is not defined' referencing the .forEach line.

Comment: You have a typo on your `.ejs` file, `listReults` instead of `listResults`

Comment: I checked and its only on my write up here, in my actual file it is spelled properly. Good catch though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to EJS, I usually use Handlebars as a template engine, but since you are passing the data in Express as an object named **list**:

```
res.render('listResults', list);
```

Have you tried with **list.listResults**?

```
<% list.listResults.forEach(function (pokemon) { %>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= pokemon.pokemon_id %></th>
    <td><%= pokemon.pokemon_name %></td>
    <td><%= pokemon.type1 %></td>
    <td><%= pokemon.type2 %></td>
    <td><%= pokemon.evLevel %></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="#" role="button">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(err){
throw err;
}else{
qryResults=res.rows;
res.render('ejsFileName',{listResults:qryResults}
);
}
```

qryResults variable will hold the query resultset then listResults will be used in the ejs file for the loop statement